# Why does the lua heap memory grow in this scenario when calling collectgarbage("count")

Tags: memory, lua, garbage-collection

Run the following lua code:

```lua
collectgarbage("collect")
collectgarbage("stop")

local a,b = {},{}

local m0 = collectgarbage("count")
local m1 = collectgarbage("count")
local m2 = collectgarbage("count")
local m3 = collectgarbage("count")
local m4 = collectgarbage("count")

print(m0 * 1024)
print(m1 * 1024)
print(m2 * 1024)
print(m3 * 1024)
print(m4 * 1024)
```

and I got these:

```
23907.0
23907.0
23907.0
24515.0
24515.0
```

With Lua 5.3 and OSX Mojave.

I'm confused why the memory usage grows after calling `collectgarbage("count")` three times.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Running the sequence of `collectgarbage()` calls involves searching that function in global environment's table and pushing it on stack, along with string argument.
Lua is pushing `collectgarbage` reports onto VM state's stack.

The stack must grow to accommodate new values being put on it, and depending on stack's current capacity, there either could be just enough space to allow all those actions done without reallocating stack, or it will have to expand stack, giving you different memory size reports.

Try inserting `print "grab stats"` in the line before the first call to `collectgarbage("count")`, after the tables being created. It's likely you won't see memory size changes at all.

Answer (score 0):

Each print converts the number to be printed to a string. These new strings need memory.

Comment: `collectgarbage("count")` returns a number, not a string.  These numbers are converted to strings only after all `m0`...`m4` are calculated.

Comment: You are right, my bad. In this case, the memory grow is indeed due to a stack reallocation, needed to execute 'collectgarbage' after some more locals were added to the stack.

Comment: `some more locals were added to the stack` - Isn't all the memory for VM registers (Proto.maxstacksize) allocated before the chunk is executed?